# In WPF, I want to dynamically set the itemsource based on combo box selection

Tags: wpf, binding, itemsource

I have a *Slider* and a *Combobox* in my view. I have 2 properties in my ViewModel. Based on the selection of the combobox, I want to bind any one of the property to the `value` of the slider.

```
 private int _xValue;

    public int XValue
    {
        get { return _xValue; }
        set
        {
            _xValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private int _yValue;

    public int YValue
    {
        get { return _yValue; }
        set
        {
            _yValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

 <StackPanel>
     <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" Margin="2" Width="100">
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="X">X</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="Y">Y</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>

    <Slider Value="{Binding XValue}"></Slider>
</StackPanel>
```

I want to bind the *Slider* `value` to `XValue` or `YValue` depending on the selection of the ComboBox

Comment: You might be better off creating two sliders, if you only want one to be visible you can bind your `Visibility` to your `ComboBox` selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` that binds to the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="2" Width="100">
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="X">X</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="Y">Y</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<Slider>
    <Slider.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Slider">
            <Setter Property="Value" Value="{Binding XValue}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Tag, ElementName=cmb}" Value="Y">
                    <Setter Property="Value" Value="{Binding YValue}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Slider.Style>
</Slider>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the binding dynamically (in XAML, at least). However, you can do the following:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}" Margin="2" Width="100">
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="X">X</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="Y">Y</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>

    <Slider Value="{Binding SliderValue}"></Slider>
</StackPanel>
```

The `Slider` is now bound to another property (`SliderValue`). Here are the added properties in your view model:

```
private int _selectedIndex;
public int SelectedIndex
{
    get { return _selectedIndex; }
    set
    {
        _selectedIndex = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();

        if (SelectedIndex == 0)
            SliderValue = XValue;
        else if (SelectedIndex == 1)
            SliderValue = YValue;
    }
}

private int _sliderValue;
public int SliderValue
{
    get { return _sliderValue; }
    set
    {
        _sliderValue = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();

        if (SelectedIndex == 0)
            XValue = SliderValue;
        else if (SelectedIndex == 1)
            YValue = SliderValue;
    }
}
```

The idea is that when the `SelectedItem` is changed via the `ComboBox`, the `Slider` is updated with either `XValue` or `YValue`. When the `Slider` value is changed, the `XValue` or `YValue` is updated depending on the `ComboBox` selection.